# Is hardware maintenance on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Suppose I have some game hardware that's damaged.  **Would it be on-topic to solicit suggestions for fixes, warranty policies, or preventative measures?**

Answer (score 10):

Suggestions, no. Suggestions get too close to recommendations to be truly useful to the internet at large.

But if you have a specific problem with your console, ask us about that.  Consoles themselves are on-topic, so if you have a problem with it, you can ask us about it, and we can give specific answers to solve the problems.

General maintenance tips might be too broad, depending on how and what you ask.  We'd have to see the question to really say.  Preventative maintenance doesn't sound specific to gaming, either; consoles are just electronics, so I'm having trouble seeing any issues that might be gaming specific.

Warranty policies are entirely out of our scope.  How companies handle their warranties are not gaming issues.